# confused by tab (\t) in printf function

Tags: c, format, printf

Consider this example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int fahr, celsius;
    int lower, upper, step;
    
    lower = 0; upper = 300; step = 20;
    
    fahr = lower;
    while (fahr <= upper) {
        celsius = 5 * (fahr - 32) / 9;
        printf("%d\t%d\n", fahr, celsius);
        fahr += step;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And get output like this:

```
0   -17
20  -6
40  4
60  15
80  26
100 37
120 48
140 60
160 71
180 82
200 93
220 104
240 115
260 126
280 137
300 148
```

since '\t' represent four white spaces, why the output so neat? It seems that the following output format is in accordance with the first one. Thanks for help!

Comment: `\t` is aligning the text with the next "tab-stop" which are at positions 4, 8, 12 etc. but the behaviour depends on the terminal. The `\t` often isn't the most useful way of formatting output.

Comment: ...it is IMO better to use, for example `printf("%-4d%d\n", fahr, celsius);` then you are not reliant on tab settings, or have to take into account (on longer fields) whether it will take up 1, or 2 tabs.

Comment: What I mean is that if the tab size is 4, and some of your outputs are length 3 and some are length 5, the output is not going to align. The length 3 will take 4 slots, and the length 5 will take 8 slots.

Comment: Is that mean the second number of first output always in the position like 4, 8, 12 etc and latter output always match the first output?

Comment: Where you output a tab character `\t` spaces are output so as to align to the next (0 mod 4) alignment. Except where is is already aligned, when 4 spaces are output. The previous size has nothing to do with it (this is not a text editor, but a terminal). It is the previous 'cursor' position on the *same* line that is relevant, not what has happened on previous lines.

Comment: As an aside, learn to use C's `for` loop construct.  Your `while` loop is more awkward than the expected `for` loop would be, i.e. `for (fahr = lower; fahr <= upper; fahr += step)`.  This encapsulates the iteration on a single line, rather than distributing it across the loop.

Comment: Well, it is an example in the book "The C Programming Language"....

Comment: Thanks Vane, very helpful explanation!

Comment: Try to set `upper` to 1100 and `step` to 100

Comment: @shino Ah, ok - I guess that example was given before the `for` loop was introduced.

Comment: By the way, when I set upper = 1000, I found the margin between output become larger but it kept neat again. What's going on in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> since '\t' represent four white spaces ...

Well, that's wrong. Tab (`\t`) is not four spaces (or any other fixed number of spaces).

Instead it means: Move to the next tab-stop.

The distance between tab-stops are a fixed number. So printing `\t` will move the cursor to a position that can be written as `N * Tab-size`.

But notice that tab-size may differ from terminal to terminal. Typically it's either 4 or 8 but it can be other values as well.

Example with tab-size equal 4:

```
Current position   Next tab-stop (i.e. new position after printing \t)
        0                4
        1                4
        2                4
        3                4
        4                8
        5                8
        6                8
        7                8
        8               12
```

and so on.

In your case as long as printing `fahr` requires 3 (or less) characters, `celsius` will always be printed at position 4.

However, if printing `fahr` requires 4 characters, you'll see `celsius` being printed at position 8.

Changing `upper` to 1200 and `step` to 200 will give:

```
0   -17
200 93
400 204
600 315
800 426
1000    537
1200    648
```

At the first 5 lines `celsius` is printed at position 4 because printing `fahr` requires less than 4 characters and consequently the **next** tab-stop is at position 4.

At the two last lines `celsius` is printed at position 8 because printing `fahr` requires 4 characters and consequently the **next** tab-stop is at position 8.

Comment: when I set upper = 1000, I found that the margin of first output become larger, it seems like new position after printing \t become 8 instead of 4.

Comment: @shino No, `\t` doesn't become 8. As I wrote: `\t` means **move to next tab-stop**. So when `fahr` is 1000, the cursor is at position 4 after printinf `fahr` **and** the next tab-stop is 8. So when printing `\t` the cursor is move to position 8. You need to get rid of the idea that `\t` is a number of spaces... it isn't.

Comment: Well, I get your meaning, but the first output is 0 and -17, in this case the cursor is not at position 4 but still move to tab-stop 8.

Comment: @shino That sounds strange... `-17` will be printed at position 4

Comment: @shino Updated the answer with an example

Comment: Well, it have different outputs in serveral platforms.... https://onlinegdb.com/RmhjQzHKF

Comment: @shino The site you linked uses tab-size equal 8. So even if you set `upper` back to 300 you'll see `celsius` being printed at position 8. And yes, different platforms/terminals/editors may use different tab-size

Comment: you are right... it's the different tab-size matter. Thanks a lot, I think I understand this problem right now.

Comment: @shino yep - different tab-size matters. And that's one reason that it's a pretty bad idea to align columns using `\t` (though exceptions exists, e.g. code indentation)

Comment: alright, get a lot from your answer. thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

`/t` is itself a character. You cannot mix it up with spaces. It is just like other characters. It too has an ASCII code (09) just like others.